# "Jolly good" meaning "extremely good" in British English

Tags: etymology, differences, american-english, british-english

Like the intensifier *bloody*, I assumed that **jolly** as an adverb and intensifier is not broadly used in the U.S. meaning *very* or *extremely*.

According to Oxford Online Dictionary, [**jolly**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jolly) as an adverb means as submodifier (British informal):

> Very; extremely: *that’s a jolly good idea*.

According to Online Etymology Dictionary, the word was used first as an adjective:

> c. 1300 (late 13c. as a surname), from Old French jolif "**festive**,
>   **merry**, **amorous**, **pretty**" (12c.) of uncertain origin (cognate with
>   Italian giulivo "merry, pleasant").

Questions:

1. When did it start to be used as an adverb and intensifier in BrE?
2. What's the difference between *jolly good* and *bloody good* in BrE?

**Edit**: I am posting the deleted question again as it is relevant.

3. Is the word never used in the U.S. as an adverb and intensifier? What would be the best counterpart of the word in AmE?

Comment: @Chenmunka I deleted the third question. Does it look better?

Comment: Have a 'jolly holiday'! Irrelevantly, in AmE 'jolly' almost only ever occurs colocated with 'Santa'

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for your comment. Can you consider posting it as an answer? I deleted a question about the difference between BrE and AmE.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would I consider positing my note about AmE usage of the word 'jolly' when your entire question is about BrE, especially since you've removed the one thing that mentions AmE?

Comment: @Mitch I edited the post to put the question No. 3 back.

Comment: I can only answer for AmE, but Jolly is never used as an intensifier...it is strictly a BrE expression.  In terms of an intensifier in current use, it depends on the situation but unfortunately the F word is now being used as an intensifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The word ***jolly*** has fourteen OED adjectival senses plus some sub-senses. Adverbially, it is sense 2a which you are discussing here:

> 2a. Qualifying an adj. or adv.; orig. appreciatively, then ironically,
>   with intensive force: Extremely, very. Now colloq.

**Examples of this sense were present from the 16th century:**

> 1549   Coverdale et al. tr. Erasmus Paraphr. Newe Test. II. Phil. iii.
>   f. viiv,   I thought my selfe a iolye fortunate man [L. pulchre mihi
>   videbar felix], aswell for the nobylitie of my kyndred..as also for my
>   strayte obseruyng of ye law.

2. The essential difference between this way of using *jolly* and *bloody* is that the latter, a much stronger intensifier, is a swear-word, and considered offensive in some circles.
3. The word is never used that way in AmE. It is rarely used at all in AmE even as an adjective except in collocations with respect to Santa Claus and related Christmas things. (point 3 contributed by @Mitch, by way of edit)

Comment: Another important difference is that [**jolly good** is a dated/declining usage, whereas **bloody good** is becoming increasingly common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jolly+good%2Cbloody+good&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjolly%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbloody%20good%3B%2Cc0) The fact that ***bloody*** hasn't yet overtaken ***jolly*** as an intensifier is just because written sources have a tendency to underrepresent "coarse vernacular". I'm sure it's already far more common in real (spoken) language.

Comment: How 'bout usage of phrases like, "You'd *jolly well better be home by eight*"? Declining as well?

Comment: @Jim The use of *jolly* is not perhaps so much declining as changing. The example you quote probably is in decline, but nowadays people use the word in other ways. For example you hear about someone *going out on a jolly* - often for something like sneaking out of work, ostensibly on employer's business, but in reality because it's more fun than sticking around the office.

Comment: @Jim -  as an intensifier I'd say yes, across the board.

Comment: @Mitch Apologies - deleted comment.

Answer (score 2):

'***Jolly***' - is an intensifier. Although it is used today in the UK with simple and non-ironic intent ('that's jolly nice of you...').  It is also used in theatre/comedy to flag a particular class of (ridiculous) cholmondley-warner-ish Englishness.

***Bloody*** - is also an intensifier, cruder and without the cultural baggage. Bloody is very common and relatively classless.

According to the OED both *jolly* and *bloody* have been used as intensifiers since the mid-1500s.